# Vs2017 doesn't show javascript error

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2017

I've imported my vs2015 project into the vs2017 and now all my javascript errors isn't shown in the text editor neither in the scrollbar like vs2015 was.[image]

How can I restore the vs2015 behavior?

Comment: The errors isn't shown in the .cshtml file neither in the .js file.

Comment: That is not a real error. You just store a reference to the function in the variable `a`.

Comment: Hi, this is an example (wrong xD).. 
it doesn't show any other errors, like
    var aaa = "hi",
    delete obj.prop;
http://imgur.com/a/wCFXb